# Add dictionary values where keys match

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like the following:

```
a=[{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3},{'a':-2},{'b':4}]
```

I need to loop through the list and add the values where the keys match. The result should look like this:

```
a=[{'a':-1},{'b':6},{'c':3}]
```

Help doing this is appreciated.

Comment: Expected output for `a=[{'a':1},{'b':2},{'a':3, 'b':4, 'c':5}]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to implement it with something like

```
a = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3},{'a':-2},{'b':4}]
b = {}

for x in a:
    k,v = x.popitem()

    # Check if the key is already in our output dict
    if k in b.keys():
        b[k] += v

    # If not, create it
    else:
        b[k] = v
```

which outputs

```
b = {'a': -1, 'b': 6, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: BEWARE: this mutates(also erases) the original

Comment: In the question his input and output dicts are labelled the same, so I took it on the assumption that the input is non-consequential. That and the problem is easily solved by cloning the input dict

Comment: I used a modified version of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

you could use a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
a=[{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3},{'a': 4},{'b':4}]
result = sum((Counter(x) for x in a),Counter())
```

This results in:

```
Counter({'b': 6, 'a': 5, 'c': 3})
```

However to work with negative counts you must use a loop:

```
c = Counter()
a=[{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3},{'a':-2},{'b':4}]
for x in a:
    c.update(x)
```

resulting in:

```
Counter({'b': 6, 'c': 3, 'a': -1})
```

These methods use a `Counter`(similar to a multiset/bag) which I think is a more useful data-structure than a list of 1-element dicts, but should be easy enough to convert to your data-structure if you really want to...

```
[{k:v} for k,v in result.items()]
```

Possibly sorting `result.items()` if order matters or something...

Comment: `dict(sum((Counter(x) for x in a),Counter()))` to get it back to `dict`

Comment: This doesn't work in the case where the values are negative. I realize I did not specify that but it must handle negative values. Question updated to reflect the requirement for negative values.

Comment: That's interesting, I can see that it breaks for negative values but I can't see any good reason _why_.

Comment: @wim imagine you had a bag of 10 marbles and someone said take out 100

Comment: Don't like the analogy.. Someone just handed me a bag of -100 marbles and all I did was mix it with my bag of 10 marbles.  I expect to either say "I have a bag of -90 marbles now", or have the universe blow up.  Instead both the bags just disappeared mysteriously..

Comment: @jamylak -- Thanks for the edit.  I was away from the computer when all of the new requirements were added ... It's nice that you updated my answer to make it still work.

Comment: @mgilson just trying to advocate the best method :)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dicts_combine(dcts):

    cd = defaultdict(int)
    for subdict in dcts:
        for k,v in subdict.items():
            cd[k] += v

    dsplit = [{k: v} for k,v in sorted(cd.items())]

    return dsplit
```

should give your desired output:

```
>>> a = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3},{'a':-2},{'b':4}]
>>> dicts_combine(a)
[{'a': -1}, {'b': 6}, {'c': 3}]
```

You can drop the `sorted`, as you like.